# Waiting time in queue of a service block by number of agents out of the service graph? AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I need to make a graph Y: Number of Agents out of Block, X: Waiting Time inside the queue of the Block.
The block is service. What is the method (if any) to get the time spent in the queue of the service block.
Or, if it is done by a function, or series of codes, can you write it step by step please, I am new to AnyLogic.

thanks...

Also, I need to make a graph of average waiting time of all process vs total time of event.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you want to have a probability density function plotted as a bar chart. The standard way to do that would be to use HistogramData(HD) object to collect samples during simulation and then plot it.

Saving data samples to HD:

- i suggest to create a variable in your agent to store the moment of time when agent entered the block, lets say you call it waitStart;
- inside your service block put this code in "on enter":
  agent.waitStart = time();
- inside your service block put this code in "on enter delay":
  yourHistogramData.add(time()-agent.waitStart);

And then you just plot your HD to the graph: right-click on you HistogramData and you will see "create chart".

As easy as that.